# Question about notation in proof of Proposition 2.C of Matsumura's "Commutative Algebra"

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, notation, artinian

I have a question about a notation in Matsumura's "Commutative Algebra". I post below a screenshot of the page in the book in which I encountered it, underlining some instances of the notation. I just don't know what it means, and I haven't been able to find anything like it. Can anyone tell me what it stands for?

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the [ideal quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_quotient). See there for elementary formulas for the ideal quotient.